# ipad_Landscape_StartImage_problem

Tags: ipad, window, orientation, landscape, splash-screen

My application supports all orientation, but i have a default screen placed at the start while i fetch the data from web-service with activity indicator, it shows fine on portrait view(with default screen followed by the image  i have added as sub view on the window) but when i start the app in Landscape mode the Default splash screen appears but the image i have added on the window does not rotate, it is added as if its in portrait. Have tried all solutions like making the window and image-view auto-flexible but its not working

Please Help

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so rotation was possible when we add the image on the window, so i decided to add it on the view and adjusted the size of the image as that of the splash screen so that there is no stretching of images horizontally and vertically. This i think is the simplest and easiest way to do it.